# Is there a name for this curve? Or, how should I describe the behavior of this graph (in words)?

Tags: terminology, article-writing

I simulated some results that look like this:

[image]

but I don't want to include the plot (my advisor is keeping me to a strict limit on figures and these are minor intermediate results).

Is there a name for this type of curve? I'm thinking of saying something like "increases sigmoidally 0 to -0.2 and from 0 to 0.2" but that sounds very clumsy to me.

Comment: I see it as an upside down right shifted pseudo-bell-curve (Not trying to be technical)

Comment: A minimum of zero at $x = 0$, increasing to approximately one for $|x| \geq 0.2$.

Comment: $1-e^{-100x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would  say something like "an upside down [*bell curve*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_curve)". Or [*Gaussian function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).

Comment: This is a comment...

Comment: @Zach466920 The OP asks how one should name/describe a curve like this. The answer is: an upside down bell cuve. IMHO your comment looks looks more like an answer in this case.

Comment: One sentence answers *are* comments...You could just add a couple of sentences addressing other possible descriptions or you could address Op's attempt at description...

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm afraid I disagree. Length is not really a notable quality of an answer if  you ask me. Correctness and clarity are what I look for.

Comment: I, for one, appreciate concise answers

Comment: I went with "an 'upside-down bell curve, decreasing sigmoidally from $0.2$ (and $-0.2$) to zero"

Comment: @ssdecontrol I personally would avoid the term *sigmoidal*. The asymtotic behaviour you want to emphasize is generally understood to be a known property of a bell curve. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @gebruiker actually in this case the sigmoid _is_ the important part

Comment: @gebruiker coming back to this question randomly over a year later, I definitely agree now that "sigmoidal" is redundant and unnecessary.